# Does ukelele custom keyboard allow multiple unicodes values for single keypress?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac

I want to create a custom keyboard in Mac. Came across ukelele, which accepts unicode value.

I am designing layout for devnagri indian language, so one character can be a combination of 2-3 unicode values, does ukelele support this?

Or only one unicode can be given at at time for a keypress

Comment: I don't know what ukelele allows, but in any case XKB doesn't allow it. Have you checked out the existing keyboard layouts and input methods (via `ibus-m17n`) for Hindi and Sanskrit?

Comment: Yes, for linux I am using ibus-m17n only. However, I want that layout for mac users also, hence ukele.

Comment: I see. I think you would need to create a custom IBus input method then, not just a custom keyboard layout.

Comment: Yes.. I have created one for linux and that works fine but want to do in mac. I came across Ukelele for mac to achieve this. But I don't want to run into the problem I came across in xkb.

Comment: Are you talking about doing it for macOS? In that case you are in the wrong place. This site is about Ubuntu.